# commonly used List of Lightning component's in salesforce

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Please let me know the commonly used  List of Lightning component's in salesforce

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackExchange.

You can look at the component library or the sample gallery Salesforce shares on Trailhead. You can see most of the commonly used components there.

> [Base Component Library](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/overview/components)
>
> [Sample Gallery](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/sample-gallery)